# Wifi Calling portability between carriers

Tags: wifi-calling

As I understand it, the major cellular carriers in the US support wifi calling. If I purchase a late model iPhone from carrier A, and I decide in the future to migrate to carrier B: is it reconfigurable to be used with carrier B's wifi calling system? (ignore CMDA / GSM compatibility)

Comment: Yes and no.  Phones are often (irritatingly) carrier locked, which you might need to deal with.  Also carrier B's SIM will also need to be installed for wifi calling to work.   When 'carrier lock' purpose was to keep the customer from switching carrier until they paid carrier A over-time for the phone it made sense.  Now unlocking is just an annoying step to prevent [theft before sale.](https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/12/17003690/verizon-phones-locked-network-date-spring-change-policy)

Comment: Beware when anyone makes a decision "to protect you"